# Number of ways to permute $\{1A, 2A, \ldots, NA, 1B, 2B, \ldots, NB\}$ such that the corresponding $iB$ occurs after $iA$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, dynamic-programming

I am solving a combinatorics problem using dynamic programming. The question asks for

> Number of ways to permute $\{1A, 2A, \ldots, NA, 1B, 2B, \ldots, NB\}$ such that the corresponding $iB$ occurs after $iA$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$?

For example, consider $N = 2$, we have 6 permutations
$$
(1A,2A,1B,2B) \\
(1A,2A,2B,1B) \\ 
(1A,1B,2A,2B) \\ 
(2A,1A,1B,2B) \\ 
(2A,1A,2B,1B) \\ 
(2A,2B,1A,1B)
$$

There is a recurrence relation between $N$ and $N+1$. Let $f(k)$ denote the number of ways to permute $N = k$, then we see that
$$
f(k + 1) = f(k) * \binom{k+3}{2} = f(k) * \frac{(k+3)(k+2)}{2}
$$

The binomial coefficient is the number of ways we can insert $(k+1)A, (k+1)B$ with replacement into $k + 2$ locations. We have the following boundary condition:
$$
f(0) = 0 \\
f(1) = 1
$$

My question is, is there a closed form solution for this problem? I tried an induction approach, but I didn't recognize any obvious pattern.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your working. The way you have described, your answer turns out to be $ \frac {(N+1)!(N+2)!} {3! \times 2^N}$ which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is.  There are $(2N)!$ permutations of $\{ 1A, 2A, \ldots, NA, 1B, 2B, \ldots, NB\}$.

We can divide these into groups of size $2^N$, where all the numbers are in the same position but the letters A/B are arranged in all the possible ways.  In each such group there will be exactly 1 permutation where $iB$ occurs after $iA$ for all $i$.  (Let's call these "good" permutations.)

For example, for $N = 2$ there are $(2\times 2)! = 24$ permutations of $\{1A, 2A, 1B, 2B\}$, and we can divide them into groups of size 4 that contain one "good" permutation.  One such group is

$$
(1A,2A,1B,2B) \\ 
(1A,2B,1B,2A) \\
(1B,2A,1A,2B) \\
(1B,2B,1A,2A) \\
$$

So there are $24/4 = 6$ good permutations with $N = 2$; more generally there are $(2N)!/2^N$ good permutations for a given value of $N$.

Comment: I like this approach but I feel like my mind gravitates towards the recursive approaches by default. What led you to think about groupings such that the numbers are in the same spot?

Comment: I think a much simpler way to state this is to arrange two sets of numbers {1, 2...N}... you can arrange it in $(2N)! / (2!)^N$ ways. That's all. Placement of A and B are fixed after that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is much simpler than you have interpreted it. There are (2n)! ways of arranging the letters. Now, for each arrangement of a and b, we have chosen permutation of that number but we just had to choose them as their order was decided. Hence, we would divide 2 for each combination of A and B. Now that we know the number of combination is n, so we would divide it by 2^n. So the answer would come as (2n!)/(2^n). I think it was easy. If you have any concern then plz comment. I would be obliged to answer you.

Comment: Actually I've made some correction. Now the answer is at its best